# GLMM data analysis in R

Tags: r, python, matlab, glmm

I am analysing some data using the glmer analysis and I would like assistance as how I could solve the following error massages. I tried fixing the problem using some examples from the internet but I don't seem to find a solution. I am trying to determine the impact 9 parameters might have on the feeding rate of insects.

model set up:

> full <- glmer(FS ~ (1 | A) + (1 | B) + (1 | C) + (1 | D) + (1 | E) +
> (1 | F) + (1 | G) + (1 |H) + (1 |I) + (1 | TR) +
> (1 | BR), data = Feed, family = binomial)
> Warning message: In checkConv(attr(opt, "derivs"), opt$par, ctrl = control$checkConv, : Model failed to converge with max|grad| = 0.0377966 (tol = 0.002, component 1)

I tried the model set up again removing one of the variables as below:

Model set up:

full <- glmer(FS ~ A + B + C + D + E + F + G + H + (1 | TR) + (1 | BR), data = Feed, family = binomial)

Message:
boundary (singular) fit: see help('isSingular').

Below is a summary of the results:

| A | B | C | D | E | F | G | H | I | TR | BR | SN | FS |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| COW | 40 | 3-5 | Dry | 18 | 400 | 35 | Dark | 0 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 1 |
| COW | 40 | 3-5 | Dry | 18 | 400 | 35 | Dark | 0 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 1 |
| COW | 20 | 7-10 | Dry | 18 | 400 | 35 | Dark | 0 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 0 |
| COW | 20 | 7-10 | Dry | 18 | 400 | 35 | Dark | 0 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 0 |
| COW | 80 | 7-10 | Dry | 18 | 400 | 35 | Dark | 0 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 1 |
| COW | 40 | 7-10 | Dry | 18 | 400 | 35 | Light | 0 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 0 |
| COW | 40 | 7-10 | Dry | 18 | 400 | 35 | Dark | 0 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 1 |
| COW | 40 | 7-10 | Dry | 18 | 400 | 35 | Dark | 5 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 1 |
| COW | 40 | 7-10 | Wet | 18 | 400 | 35 | Dark | 0 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 0 |

Where:

A: Parameter 1 |B: Parameter 2|C: Parameter 3 |D: Parameter 4|E: Parameter 5 |F: Parameter 6 |G: Parameter 7 |H: Parameter 8|I: Parameter 9 |TR: technical replicate |BR: biological replicate|SN: Number assigned to insect |FS: Feeding status ( 0 = Not fed; 1 =Fed)

When each parameter was evaluated, the other parameter remains constant. Therefore, they are not always fixed variables

Comment: Can you explain in words why you have included random intercepts for all your predictors but no fixed effects?